# How to force Tor to obtain IP from specific country? [ExitNodes already added to torrc. No good]

Tags: proxy, ip, python, tor

I used [this guide](http://sacharya.com/crawling-anonymously-with-tor-in-python/) to install Tor on amazon EC2 instance. I use python to access some websites, and I want to access those sites by a US IP. As it is mentioned [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node) I added following lines to the etc/tor/torrc file, restarted Tor, and still I get random IPs from random countries.

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:H____mypasswordhash________H
ExitNodes {us}
StrictNodes 1
```

How can I force Tor to get IPs from specific country?
Is it a problem because I am using Amazon EC2?

Comment: check that answer: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node

Comment: Thanks Serge, but I have seen that post already, it does not work for me though. I already have ExitNodes and StrictNodes set in the torrc. Is there anything else I should do?